# How add jQuery ui auto complete to dynamic content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-events

I have some input created dynamically in a web page and every input need an autocomplete options with ajax request.
Every input have same class.

I created that for one input but when other inputs created by user the autocomplete not working for them.

I use something like below:

```
$('.class').autocomplete(options);
```

How can correct this problem?

Comment: Reinitialize `autocomplete` on newly added element...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function .live() is deprecated now.

```
var options = {
    source: ["ActionScript", "AppleScript"],
    minLength: 2
};
var selector = 'input.searchInput';
$(document).on('keydown.autocomplete', selector, function() {
    $(this).autocomplete(options);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this in your ajax code after the code where you're adding new element

```
$('.newElement').autocomplete(options);
```

> You need to initialize autocomplete the each dynamically added element.